# Do locally compact Hausdorff spaces admit local bases consisting of normal open neighbourhoods?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological space.

By locally compact we mean that every $x\in X$ admits a local basis consisting of compact neighbourhoods.

Then since compact Hausdorff spaces are normal, each $x\in X$ admits a local basis consisting of normal neighbourhoods.

My question is whether it must be the case that each $x\in X$ admits a local basis consisting of normal *open* neighbourhoods.

An issue preventing this from being a completely straightforward deduction is the existence of compact Hausdorff spaces which are not completely normal, e.g. the [Tychonoff plank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_plank).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: let $x \in U$, $U$ open in $X$. Then there is a compact neighbourhood $W \subset U$ of $x$. Since $X$ is locally compact (and Hausdorff), it is completely regular. Hence there is a cozero set $V$ such that $x \in V \subset W$. Of course, $V$ is open. As a cozero set, $V$ is $F_\sigma$ in $X$ and also in $W$. Since $W$ is normal, and $F_\sigma$ subsets of normal spaces are normal (see, for instance, Engelking, General topology, 2.1.E), $V$ is normal.

Comment: Thank you. I must say, this is a great use of the $F_\sigma$ property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Just a nitpick, you must have meant: "Since $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff" (otherwise completely regularity is not guaranteed).

Comment: @PatrickR: well, in my world locally compact spaces *are* Hausdorff. 
Of course, otherwise this should be mentioned as you suggested.
Please note that the OP generally assumed that X is Hausdorff. Of course, in a "locally compact", non-Hausdorff space elements do not need to have normal neighborhoods at all (e.g. cofinite topology on the integers).
Anyway, I added Hausdorff in my answer. Thank you for clarification!